# Delphi: XOR vs <> for booleans

Tags: delphi, boolean, xor, inequality

Is there any difference between :

```
procedure InequalityMsg(ABool1, ABool2 : Boolean);
begin
  if ABool1 <> ABool2 then
    ShowMessage('Yeah, they''re not the same');
end;
```

and

```
procedure InequalityMsg(ABool1, ABool2 : Boolean);
begin
  if ABool1 XOR ABool2 then
    ShowMessage('Yeah, they''re not the same');
end;
```

Comment: I was thinking `<>` was an alternative `xor` operator in Delphi... but quickly realized that's just `ABool1 != ABool2`, silly me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are exactly the same. (Well, the generated code might differ, but the behaviour will never show any difference. And, as performance goes, this question is very unimportant.)

Comment: Yeah, I figured wasn't exactly a pressing issue.  I was just wondering because ABool1 = ABool2 is the same as Abool1 AND ABool2 and if you were just looking at truth tables for and and xor you wouldn't think that they'd have equal and opposite operators like = and <> are.  I just needed a little closure.

Comment: AND and = don't give same result.

Comment: (false and false) = false, (false = false) = true

Comment: @Peter: David is right. The logical operator that would correspond to = is equivalence, <=>.

Comment: There may be subtle differences if your `Boolean` variable has acquired its value through by type-casting an integer that didn't have a value of 0 or 1. (When you type-cast, you tell the compiler that you know what you're doing, and it trusts you.) You could end up with two non-zero variables that are also non-equal. If you're type-casting integers, you should use `LongBool`, `WordBool`, or `ByteBool` instead of `Boolean`. Delphi assumes that `Boolean` will only have two possible binary values; it doesn't make the same assumption for the other types.

Comment: Rob, you should post your comment as an answer. :)